# How to request login for user but not for bots

Tags: functions, customization, redirect, login

I wondering, how to not requesting bots like google crawler or bing crawlers to login since they can crawl my post info, but require user to login if they want to see the posts?

I already know how to redirect user to login page, but don't know how to exclude the crawlling bots!

```
function wpse_41699_wp(){
    if( is_page('Login')||is_page('register')||is_page('Blog')||is_page('blog') ){
        return;
    }else{
        if(!is_user_logged_in()){
            $url = get_bloginfo('home').'/login';//ACW-login location need to be specified
            header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**Or is there better way to do this?**

Comment: there isn't a bulletproof way to do this, anyone can make their browser masquerade as a search bot.

Comment: @Milo, I try to maybe just prevent average users, do you think its possible to do?

Comment: You'd have to check [User Agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/)... not very reliable as UA strings are subject to change, not very practical-- aka, "a lot of work".

Comment: Also, "the average user" can easily install and use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

Comment: There is a Stack Overflow thread that might help you: [Regexp that matches user-agents of end-user browsers but NOT crawlers with >90 % accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2508214/299509).